# How to disable all buttons but one, then enable all with click using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am trying to make a simple on/off switch with jQuery and it is disabling all buttons, including the on/off.

```
$(".onOff").click(function() {
  $('button').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

How can I prevent this from disabling the button when clicked?

Comment: works for me. which version of JQuery you are using

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, alternatively you can be specific inside the function using selector `$('button:not(".onOff")')`

```js
$(".onOff").click(function() {
  $('button').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="onOff">ON / OFF</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
```

Comment: Strange, it is still not working for me. I am using the same version of jQuery as you. Any ideas why this still isn't working?

Comment: Do you have any other `$` reference assigned on your local environment? Like Tampermoney or greesemonkey running?

Comment: No, I don't. I am also using several bootstrap classes on the button. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: I guess best thing you could do for us to diagnose is try to replicate as close as possible and update your question so that we can take a look and answer accordingly.

Comment: Nevermind, just found the issue. I had the onOff class inside a div, not the button. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Below the disable, try putting this: `$(this).prop(‘disabled’, false);`.

Comment: 1. `$(this)` 2. check those quotes

Comment: I altered my response to include `$(this)`. Sorry, I am still learning JQ. Also, since I am using an iPad to type these, I can’t fix the quotation marks.

Comment: @Hoss Check it out now.